# How can I dynamically add radio buttons to an activity?

Tags: java, android

I have an activity where users can change a setting using radio buttons. There may be anywhere from 2 to 7 options, so I want to dynamically add the radio buttons in my onCreate(). With a bit of research I figured out how to do it and documented the results for my own benefit and yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, include the radio group widget and and declare one. You’ll also need LayoutParams and RadioButton, so include those as well.

```
    //SomeAndroidActivity
    import android.widget.RadioGroup;
    import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
    import android.widget.RadioButton;

    public class SomeAndroidActivity extends Activity () {
        //declare a radio group
        RadioGroup radioGroup;
    }
```

Inside your onCreate method, initialize the radio group.

```
    //SomeAndroidActivity

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_some_android);
      radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_selection_group);
    }
```

R.id.radio_selection_group is referring to a radio group that’s declared in your XML file, so make sure you have that as well.

```
    <!-- activity_some_android.xml -->
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android=
        "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      tools:context=".SomeAndroidActivity" >

      <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_selection_group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="76dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="135dp" >

      </RadioGroup>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Back in SomeAndroidActivity, create a method to dynamically add buttons to the radio group.

```
    //SomeAndroidActivity
    private void addRadioButtons(int numButtons) {
      for(int i = 0; i < numButtons; i++)
        //instantiate...
        RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(this);

        //set the values that you would otherwise hardcode in the xml...
        radioButton.setLayoutParams 
          (new LayoutParams 
          (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        //label the button...
        radioButton.setText("Radio Button #" + i);
        radioButton.setId(i);

        //add it to the group.
        radioGroup.addView(radioButton, i);
      }
    }
```

Then call that method in onCreate.

```
    //SomeAndroidActivity
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_some_android);
      radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_selection_group);

      int numberOfRadioButtons = 7;
      addRadioButtons(numberOfRadioButtons);
    }
```

Easy pie.

Here's my blog post about it. 
http://rocketships.ca/blog/how-to-dynamically-add-radio-buttons/